# Retrofit RxAndroid make wrapper for api calls

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I wanted to create a wrapper for api calls in retrofit so I can display ProgressDialog at common place & handle common response.

I achieved this by creating wrapper like this

```
public static <T> Observable<T> callApiWrapper(final Context context,
                                                   final boolean shouldShowProgress,
                                                   final String message,
                                                   final Observable<T> source) {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        if (shouldShowProgress) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
                progressDialog.setMessage(message);
            else
                progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.please_wait));
        }


        return source.lift(new Observable.Operator<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> child) {
                return new Subscriber<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        super.onStart();

                        if (shouldShowProgress) {
                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    progressDialog.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        child.onStart();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        if (shouldShowProgress && progressDialog.isShowing())
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        child.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        if (shouldShowProgress && progressDialog.isShowing())
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        child.onError(e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(T t) {

                        /*
                            Handle Invalid API response
                         */

                        if (((BaseResponse) t).getStatus() == RestParams.Codes.INVALID_API_KEY) {
                            mCommonDataModel.setApiKey("");
                            getCommonApiService().getApiKey()
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseBody>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted() {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {

                                            try {
                                                String response = responseBody.string();
                                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                                String key = jsonObject.optString("KEY");

                                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(key))
                                                    mCommonDataModel.setApiKey(key);

                                                callApiWrapper(context, shouldShowProgress,
                                                        message, source)
                                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                        .subscribe();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            if (shouldShowProgress && progressDialog.isShowing())
                                progressDialog.dismiss();


                            child.onNext(t);
                        }

                    }
                };
            }
        });

    }
```

In the above code, I check that if I get specific status code like Invalid API KEY, then I am calling an API to get the new API key instead of giving the status directly to original subscriber.

Once I get the new API key successfully, I call the wrapper recursively & try to give the response to original subscriber. But the problem is Original Subscriber is not getting `onNext` callback

What am I missing here? Is there any other way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: Seems like you have two separate issues. One is your side-effect and the other is getting a new API key if the first is invalid. You shouldn't need a wrapper for either.

Comment: It might be invalid, but I don't have control over how APIs are developed so I am asked to handle it in this way. There are some other validations as well where a common wrapper would make sense instead of repeating validations in every API response. Regarding side-effect, I didn't get you. Can you please explain how this can be done in better way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to create a wrapper which handles for me the common Progressbar & retry logic in case of Invalid Key API Response. This kind of wrapper might be useful if in many cases. Thanks to @JohnWowUs for his answer which helped me to understand things & implement this wrapper.

Here's the working code

```
private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 2;
private static int sCurrentRetryAttempt = 0;

/**
     * Common Wrapper for calling API.
     *
     * @param context            context for showing progress dialog
     * @param shouldShowProgress boolean which indicated if progress dialog should be shown or not
     * @param message            message to be shown in progress dialog. if null passed, then "Please wait..." will be shown
     * @param source             original observable
     * @return observable to which observer can subscribe
     */
    public static <T> Observable<T> callApiWrapper(final Context context,
                                                      final boolean shouldShowProgress,
                                                      final String message,
                                                      final Observable<T> source) {

        // Progress Dialog
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = setupProgressDialog(context, shouldShowProgress, message);
        if (progressDialog != null) progressDialog.show();

        return source
                .flatMap(new Func1<T, Observable<T>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<T> call(T t) {

                        /*
                         * Check if the response contains invalid key status code.
                         */

                        if (t instanceof BaseResponse) {
                            if (((BaseResponse) t).getStatus() == RestParams.Codes.INVALID_API_KEY) {
                                return Observable.error(new InvalidKeyException("Invalid key"));
                            }
                        }

                        /*
                         * We are here, that means, there wasn't invalid key status code.
                         * So we wouldn't like to handle it so just return to original subscriber
                         */
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        return Observable.just(t);
                    }
                }).retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {

                        return observable.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<?> call(final Throwable throwable) {
                                if (throwable instanceof InvalidKeyException) {
                                    /*
                                     * Check for retry limit. if we already have retried enough, then
                                     * we should tell the original subscriber about the error as it
                                     * doesn't seems recoverable.
                                     */
                                    if (sCurrentRetryAttempt >= MAX_RETRIES) {
                                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                                        //Resetting the attempts to 0
                                        sCurrentRetryAttempt = 0;
                                        return Observable.error(throwable);
                                    }

                                    //Increase the attempt counter
                                    sCurrentRetryAttempt += 1;
                                    return getCommonApiService().getApiKey()
                                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                            .flatMap(new Func1<ResponseBody, Observable<?>>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public Observable<?> call(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                                                    try {
                                                        /*
                                                         * Check if we succeed in our attempt to handle
                                                         * invalid key
                                                         */
                                                        if (processApiKey(responseBody)) {

                                                            /*
                                                             * We succeeded in our attempts to handle
                                                             * invalid api key, so we will return the
                                                             * original subscriber what it wanted.
                                                             */
                                                            return callApiWrapper(context,
                                                                    shouldShowProgress, message, source);
                                                        } else
                                                            return Observable.just(throwable);
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                                        /*
                                                         * We are here that means something went wrong,
                                                         * so we will retry silently.
                                                         */
                                                        return Observable.just(throwable);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                } else {
                                    /*
                                     * For any other error, we are not going to handle right now,
                                     * so just return
                                     */
                                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
```

& using this is same as normal like:

```
RestClient.callApiWrapper(mContext, true, null,
                RestClient.getAuthenticationApiService().socialLogIn(name, email, singInVia, mobile, "android", deviceToken))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<BaseResponse<RegistrationResponse>>() {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some retry logic in case you get an invalid key failure so something like

```
source.flatMap(
    t -> 
    {
        if (((BaseResponse) t).getStatus() == RestParams.Codes.INVALID_API_KEY) {
            return Observable.error(new InvalidKeyException("The key is not valid"));
        }
        else {
            return Observable.just(t);
        }
    }
)
.retryWhen(
    errors -> 
        errors.flatMap(error -> {  

            if (error instanceof InvalidKeyException()) {
                return getCommonApiService().getApiKey()                                         
                                            .flatMap(
                                                responseBody -> {
                                                    String response = responseBody.string();
                                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                                    String key = jsonObject.optString("KEY");

                                                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(key))
                                                        return Observable.error();
                                                else {
                                                    return Observable.just(key);
                                                }})
                                            .doOnNext( key -> mCommonDataModel.setApiKey(key));
            }
            // For anything else, don't retry
            return Observable.error(error);
        }))
.subscribe(/* do what you need to do with the results*/)
```

In order to add the side effects i.e. enable progress bar when you start the subscription and dismiss it when you've finished something like

```
modifiedSource.doOnSubscribe(/* progress bar show logic */)
              .doOnTerminate(/* progress bar dismiss logic */)
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this in this way but as any API can get the invalid key exception so in this way I will have to write repeating code everywhere. That's why I want to create a wrapper.