# What is the best practices for retry mechanism while using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

**Problem Statement:**

I'm using Retrofit in my application for API calls. Currently I've 20+ Retrofit Interfaces, with different `Callbacks`. Currently when app receives `INVALID_SESSION_ID` in anyone of these Interfaces (say `UpdateUserAPI`), I've to get new `ACCESS_TOKEN`, by invoking `AccessTokenAPI`.

**Approach Suggested:**

When app receives `INVALID_SESSION_ID` in `Callback` in `UpdateUserAPI`, invoke `AccessTokenAPI` to get new `ACCESS_TOKEN`. Upon receiving new `ACCESS_TOKEN`, post the actual call (with initial parameters in `UpdateUserAPI`) with new `ACCESS_TOKEN`. But this requires to save parameters in the class which implements `UpdateUserAPI`. Also I need to retry getting `ACCESS_TOKEN` only once, which should be handled.

**What is the best approach to implement above requirement?**

Comment: I was having the similar requirement & had created a wrapper for all API calls. Have a look at this if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45457595/1852343

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own TokenInterceptor

```
public class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor
```

Then set it to your okktpclient

```
Interceptor tokenInterceptor = new TokenInterceptor(provideUserLoginDao(appDatabase));
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
                .writeTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();
```

Useful information in this post also : [Refreshing OAuth token using Retrofit without modifying all calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450036/refreshing-oauth-token-using-retrofit-without-modifying-all-calls)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom interceptor and check your token/session_id is  valid or not. If your session_id is expired and then hit your updateUserAPI to get new id and set this id in header or where you want. Here is some code samples.

**RefreshTokenInterceptor**

```
    public static class RInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        try {
            if (response.code() == 410) {

                Response r = null;
                try {

                    r = makeTokenRefreshCall(request, chain);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return r;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}


  private static Response makeTokenRefreshCall(Request req, Interceptor.Chain chain) throws JSONException, IOException {
    /* fetch refreshed token, some synchronous API call, whatever Because we are responsible to return new response  */
    refreshTokenSync();
    Request newRequest;
    newRequest = req.newBuilder().header("authorization", NEW_TOKEN)/*.post(req.body())*/.build();
    return chain.proceed(newRequest);


}
```

**RESTClient**

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(55, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                   .addInterceptor(new NetworkInterceptor())
                    .build();
```